# Functions - Inverses of graphs.

Tags: functions, inverse

The question reads: sketch the graph of y=-3-x along with its inverse.

From calculating the equation of the inverse graph, I come to y=-3-x, using the swap method. I then tried to plot both graphs but they are the exact same, so where does the line of symmetry lie? I can't seem to figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Guys, would a straight line and its inverse always be functions. The vertical line test is done to see if it is a function and in this case, on a straight line graph, it is going to cut the graph only once meaning that all straight line graphs and their inverses are always functions. Could anyone confirm this for me. Thanks.

Comment: All straight lines *except vertical ones* represent functions. A vertical line obviously does not pass the vertical line test, since that vertical line intersects the graph infinitely many times. All other lines *except horizontal ones* are functions and have inverse functions. Horizontal lines represent functions but are not one-to-one: they obviously do not pass the horizontal line test. Therefore all non-vertical-and-non-horizontal lines are functions and have inverse functions. These inverses are of course also functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: the function defined by your equation is its own inverse. That is not uncommon, and I have my class deal with several similar functions in homework and a test. Some examples are $y=\frac 1x$ and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2},\ 0\le x\le 1$.

The line of symmetry for all self-inverse functions is the line $y=x$. Your graph also has another line of symmetry, namely itself, but that will not hold for all self-inverse functions. The lines $y=x+c$ for constant $c$ are also lines of symmetry, but again only the one for $c=0$ is important for your question.

Answer (score 3):

The line of symmetry is the line $y=x$.

The function $y=-3-x$ is perpendicular to the line and is its own inverse.

Comment: this is very nice(+1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes the inverse is symmetric to the line $y=x$.

So in this case:

$y=-3-x\therefore x=-3-y\therefore x+3=-y\therefore y=-x-3$

So, $y^{-1}=-x-3$ would be the inverse. And if you plotted $y$ and $y^{-1}$ on a graph, you would see that they are symmetric on the line $y=x$